# Parsing piped response sometimes gets chunked data

Tags: node.js, stream, request, pipe, response

I have a nodejs proxy for calling a service. On the response, the request is piped to the service url (I guess that's the right way to do it if you want to parse the response before returning it). The problem is that the parser sometimes fails on JSON.parse(data) because it Unexpected end of input. From what I saw while debugging the issue is that the data being parsed is not complete (even though the service returns it properly).
I don't have too much experience with pipe and stream so I'm not sure why this is failing sometimes.

```
//Request setup
            r.on('response', function(resp) {
            if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
                r.pipe(responseParser(config.get('service:url'))).pipe(res);
            } else {
                r.pipe(res);
            }
        });

//Parser module
    var _ = require('lodash'),
        stream = require('stream');

    module.exports = function responseParser(url) {
        var data = '',
            parser = new stream.Transform({
                objectMode: true
            });

        parser._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
            data += chunk.toString();
            done();
        };

        parser._flush = function (done) {
            if (data) {
                var obj = mapValues(JSON.parse(data));
                    this.push(JSON.stringify(obj));
            }

            done();
        };

        function mapValues(data){
            ...
        }

        return parser;
    }
```

I still don't know why sometimes the flush gets called before all the chunks of data are returned but what I did in order to avoid that is just to parse the chunks as they arrived, by making sure that in a chunk I don't get partial data on the values I needed to map. If a chunk contains only partial information for the targeted value, I remove it, and add it at the beginning of the next chunk. This way the data is parsed as it comes in so I don't have to rely on the fact that flush is called only when all the data has returned.

Comment: Why are you using `objectMode: true` if you're just pushing a string after the parser is closed?

Comment: Unfortunately it's shared code that I'm trying to decipher so I just found it like that. It doesn't look like it's pushing any string after the parser is closed. Could that be the culprit?

Comment: `this.push(JSON.stringify(obj));` is pushing a string.

Comment: I thought that the parser will be closed after the flush -> https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_flush_callback. Because I don't know exactly how the pipe should work together with the stream parser I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would disable `objectMode` as it's not necessary in this case. Also, you'll want to wrap the JSON parsing in a try-catch in case of malformed input:

```
module.exports = function responseParser(url) {
  var data = '';
  var parser = new stream.Transform();
  parser._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
    data += chunk;
    done();
  };
  parser._flush = function(done) {
    var err;
    if (data) {
      try {
        var obj = mapValues(JSON.parse(data));
        this.push(JSON.stringify(obj));
        this.push(null);
      } catch (ex) {
        err = ex;
      }
    }
    done(err);
  };

  function mapValues(data){
    // ...
  }

  return parser;
};
```

You may also want to check that `resp.headers['content-type']` contains `application/json` first before trying to parse it as such and you may want to make a custom Transform subclass and instantiate that instead of creating new `_transform()` and `_flush()` functions every time.

Comment: So you think it's the service returning the chunked data? I suspect that something goes wrong in the pipe + stream because the same call returns the entire JSON object sometimes... Also, from all the proxied calls to the backend service, this issue appears on only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing this yourself, why don't you use a streaming JSON parser that knows how to parse a stream? [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream) for example.

The other option to make your life easier would be to use [stream-to-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-to-promise) to just convert the read stream into a Promise that will resolve to a Buffer of the JSON, which you can then parse.

Also, why is your proxy parsing the JSON?

Comment: The proxy is parsing the JSON because the result should hide some urls from the response. Those urls could have probably be passed to the service but I have no power over changing that bit. I will look into the JSONStream and stream-to-promise options. Maybe it helps clean the code a bit.

Comment: Hello, I finally had a chance to take a closer look at JSONStream and it looks like it's used to filter JSON content while I need to replace only some values of certain keys in my response. The stream-to-promise looked more interesting but I didn't figure out how to pipe the parsed result to the response.